# How to get large size JSON files using requests module in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to save a large `JSON` file into a variable using `requests` module but only part of the `JSON` is making it into the variable when using the following:

```
r = requests.get(url)

r.json()
```

I see there are ways to save it in chunks when writing to a file is there a way to do this when writing to a variable?

Comment: "I see there are ways to save it in chunks when writing to a file is there a way to do this when writing to a variable?" — No.  Without more information (e.g., what you expect to be in the variable versus what's actually ending up in there), we can't tell you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) , using 'with' and setting stream to True should get you what you need.

```
with requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', stream=True) as r:
    # Do things with the response here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
response.close()
```

Or you can use context manager:

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
```

## Update:

To a variable, it is the same, just use `data += chunk`